# Using CASE in WHERE clause in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

I have a select statement like below :

```
 SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT d.value, d.line, d.language, l.pos_id, l.vehicle_id,l.vehicle_given
    FROM Vehicle_value d,
    vehicle_document l
    WHERE d.gen_id = l.gen_id
    AND d.pos_id = l.pos_id
    AND d.gen_id = 1255) d1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT d.value, d.line, d.language, l.pos_id, l.vehicle_id,l.vehicle_given
    FROM TBB_GEN_Daten d,
    TBB_GEN_Lesehilfe l
    FROM Vehicle_value d,
    vehicle_document l,
    WHERE d.gen_id = l.gen_id
    AND d.pos_id = l.pos_id
    AND d.gen_id = 1254) d2
    ON d1.value = d2.value
    AND d1.pos_id = d2.pos_id
    AND case when d1.vehicle_given = 'YES' then (d1.vehicle_id = d2.vehicle_id)
             else end
    AND d1.value is not null;
```

So I wanted to compare the d1.vehicle_id to d2.vehicle_id only when the d1.vehicle_given value is 'YES'. But the case statement i have used here is wrong and hence it doesnt work. is there any other to do this comparision ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch of typos in your code, but - when fixed, and with CASE being rewritten - query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT d.VALUE,
               d.line,
               d.language,
               l.pos_id,
               l.vehicle_id,
               l.vehicle_given
          FROM Vehicle_value d, vehicle_document l
         WHERE     d.gen_id = l.gen_id
               AND d.pos_id = l.pos_id
               AND d.gen_id = 1255) d1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT d.VALUE,
                               d.line,
                               d.language,
                               l.pos_id,
                               l.vehicle_id,
                               l.vehicle_given
                          FROM TBB_GEN_Daten d,
                               TBB_GEN_Lesehilfe l,
                               Vehicle_value d,
                               vehicle_document l
                         WHERE     d.gen_id = l.gen_id
                               AND d.pos_id = l.pos_id
                               AND d.gen_id = 1254) d2
          ON     d1.VALUE = d2.VALUE
             AND d1.pos_id = d2.pos_id
             AND d1.vehicle_id =
                 CASE
                    WHEN d1.vehicle_given = 'YES' THEN d2.vehicle_id
                    ELSE d1.vehicle_id
                 END
             AND d1.VALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This will not match when `d1.vehicle_id` is `NULL` and `d1.vehicle_given <> 'YES'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets and an `OR` condition for either the matching condition or when it is not `YES`:

```sql
 AND (  d1.vehicle_given <> 'YES'
     OR d1.vehicle_given IS NULL
     OR d1.vehicle_id = d2.vehicle_id )
```

---

If you use a `CASE` expression such as:

```sql
AND d1.vehicle_id = CASE
                    WHEN d1.vehicle_given = 'YES'
                    THEN d2.vehicle_id
                    ELSE d1.vehicle_id
                    END
```

Then when the `ELSE` condition is matched you will effectively end up with `AND d1.vehicle_id = d1.vehicle_id`. This, naively, looks like it should be fine but if `d1.vehicle_id` is `NULL` then you will end up comparing `NULL = NULL` and the result is not truthy and the row will be excluded and that is not what you want.